# Is it possible to use another setter in a useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href

I'm working on a search results filter which is controlled by clicking on a button, opening a dropdown menu, selecting checkboxes for each filter, and clicking on an "Apply" button. I'm trying to get this button to change the href on click, but it seems to be a step behind. In my experience, when this issue of being a step behind comes up, it usually has something to do with the state management.

I'm able to see that `selected` (which is the chosen filters) updates correctly. But when logging the `href`, it's always a bit behind. Could this be because there's no dependency for `href` in my useEffect?

**Example**: user selects the "document" filter from the dropdown menu and clicks "Apply". After clicking, they see `['documentType']` in the logs for `selected`. But for the `href` log, they see `?`. Then the user selects the "folder" filter in addition to the previous selection aand `selected` is logged as `['documentType, 'folderType']` and `href` is logged as `?types=pdf`.

```
const translatedTypesArray = [
    ['document', 'documentType'],
    ['folder', 'folderType'],
    ['image', 'imageType'],
];

type Props = {
    getBaseHref: (overrides: Object) => string,
    types: string,
};

const SearchFilterType = ({ getBaseHref, types }: Props) => {
    const typesArray = types ? types.split(',') : [];
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(typesArray);
    const [href, setHref] = React.useState('#');

    const getHref = () => {
        const typesFilters = [];
        translatedTypesArray.forEach(([type, translationID]) => {
            const isSelected = selected.includes(translationID);
            if (isSelected) {
                typesFilters.push(type);
            }
        });
        return getBaseHref({ types: typesFilters.join(',') || undefined });
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // this shows which filter item is selected
        console.log(selected); 
        const selectedHref = getHref();
        setHref(selectedHref);
        // this shows the href after calling the setter, but it's always one step
        // behind here
        console.log(href);
    }, [selected]);

    const handleOnApply = (event: any) => {
        setSelected(event);
    };

    return (
     <RouterLink href={href}>
        <ItemTypeSelectorQuickFilter onApply={e => handleOnApply(e)} selected={selected} />
     </RouterLink>
    );
};

export default SearchFilterType;
```

Comment: That is normal behavior for react and is part of it's declarative nature.  This is actually probably the most common question posted here.

Comment: @possum I see, if I need to use the `href` to redirect the page after applying the filters, would this behavior cause a problem??

Comment: Why not use the variable selectedHref to do the redirect?

Comment: @James Hm, do you mean using that variable as the href attribute in some kind of a RouterLink (wrapped around the quick filter component)?

Comment: In your previous comment you mentioned using href to redirect the page.  I'm saying just use selectedHref to do it (however you are planning on doing it).

Comment: @James Oh I see, yeah, I've tried doing that but it takes two button clicks for the filters to actually be applied :( I rendered the href too in the return value and i can see that it changes correctly there. But for whatever reason, the react router doesn't route properly until the second button click

Comment: Calling setHref will assure that href is updated *before the next render*.  It doesn't change the current value of href.